# How can I exchange a hash password for a newer one at AIX and Linux using shell script?

Tags: unix, shell-script, bash-scripting, sh, hashing

We have AIX and Linux machines that we can use puppet to change password automatically.

But in some cases we need to do this manually. But I decide to write a script and change the old hash with a newer one.

I tried to mix two different scripts to do this:

1st step)

```
#!/bin/bash
# function
$os = 'uname -a | grep AIX'
if [ $os = 'AIX']
then
  $dir='/etc/security/passwd'
else
  $dir='/etc/shadow'
fi
```

2nd step) Take the old hash and put blank space (but I would like to put the new hash):

```
function exchange_hash () {
echo "Extract hash..."
pass=`cat $dir | grep $user | awk -F: '{print $2}'`
}
```

How could I call the function and replace the old hash with a newer one. I just entering:

1st parameter -> username

2nd parameter -> newhash

The script need to work both AIX\Linux. I know that I have to invoke sh to call the script on AIX.

Tks in advance!

Comment: Basically: don't. If you want to change passwords for your script, use `expect`

Comment: I find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command
But did not catch, what you want to explain about expect statement...? @LorinczyZsigmond

Comment: expect(1) is a program to run interactive programs non-interactively.